# Is there a way in Robot framework to log if keywork only if there are True?

Tags: python, logging, automated-tests, testng, robotframework

I do know that there are no switch statements in RF. I do have 50 if-keywords (that I use because no switch exists).
My log file is very long because literally every 50 if statements are logged (even those who are not true).
I would like to know if there is a way to log only the statements that are true?

here is how my code is written (there are 50 keywords like these) :

```
# Access Apply ImportExportParams
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'ImportExportParams' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'    Call_API_ImportExportParams    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}    ${ProductId}
# Access bulk apply cheapest quote
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'BulkApplyCheapest' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'    Call_API_BulkApplyCheapest    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}    ${ProductId}
# SiteSelection
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'SiteSelection' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'     Call_API_SiteSelection    ${ProductId}    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}    ${Name}
# SiteSelectionFile
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'SiteSelectionFile' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'     Call_API_SiteSelectionFile    ${ProductId}    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'SiteSelectionFile2' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'     Call_API_SiteSelectionFile2    ${ProductId}    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}
# SiteSelectionMultiple
\    Run Keyword If    '${Type}' == 'SiteSelectionMultiple' and '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'     Call_API_SiteSelectionMultiple    ${ProductId}    ${DealId}    ${ScenarioId}
```

[image: here is a screenshot of a part of my actual log]

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about such feature in the framework, but I can think of an alternative. You could write a small [library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) which is [recommended](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#conditional-execution) by the user guide for such cases.

> In general, it is not recommended to have conditional logic in test cases, or even in user keywords, because it can make them hard to understand and maintain. Instead, this kind of logic should be in test libraries, where it can be implemented using natural programming language constructs. However, some conditional logic can be useful at times, and even though Robot Framework does not have an actual if/else construct, there are several ways to get the same effect.

Here is an example to get you started.

Library code (lib.py):

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def switch(type):
    type = int(type)
    if type == 1:
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('Log Many', 'arg1 - case1', 'arg2 - case1') # call any keyword like it was called from Robot Framework
    elif type == 11:
        BuiltIn().fail('Fail as it was 11') # or throw exception, that will fail the test execution as well
        
    if type == 2:
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('Log', 'arg1  - case2') # call any keyword like it was called from Robot Framework
    elif type == 22:
        BuiltIn().fail('Fail as it was 22') # or throw exception, that will fail the test execution as well

    if type == 3:
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('No operation') # call any keyword like it was called from Robot Framework
    elif type == 33:
        BuiltIn().fail('Fail as it was 33') # or throw exception, that will fail the test execution as well

    if type == 4:
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('Log To Console', 'arg1  - case4') # call any keyword like it was called from Robot Framework
    elif type == 44:
        BuiltIn().fail('Fail as it was 44') # or throw exception, that will fail the test execution as well
```

Usage in test.robot (execute  `robot test.robot`, Python and robot file should be in the same directory.
[image]

Also the `--pythonpath` argument could be used or PYTHONPATH env variable could be updated with the path of the library if the library must be at another location.):

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ${CURDIR}/lib.py

*** Test Cases ***
A test 1
    switch    1
    
A test 2
    switch    2
    
A test 3
    switch    3
    
A test 4
    switch    4
    
A test 5
    switch    11
    
A test 6
    switch    22
    
A test 7
    switch    33
    
A test 8
    switch    44
    
A test 9
    switch    5
```

This is the output where you can see only the executed branch.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your proposition. I can create a library as long as I'm working on my local environment. But we are a team working on a server, and I have to use only already made libraries, my code as to be versatile

Comment: @LouGyde So basically, you are not allowed to put a small Python file next to your robot file?

Comment: The lib could be as generic as you want I think, my example is a bit specific as it is just an idea.

Comment: @LouGyde I have updated the answer, so that the robot file will refer to the Python lib directly so there is no need to use `--pythonpath` or to update PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Hello, sorry to look at that only now. your solution is really interesting. do you think that I can transform my long list of if using a switch keyword in an annexed library? You maybe if all the if are in a library instead of directly the code it will not throw exceptions ? thanks for the answer

Comment: @LouGyde I think you can a lib. As for the exceptions, it does not matter if it happens in Python or Robot, it will be thrown. The difference is that you can catch an exception in Python using `try`, `catch` blocks while in Robot it will simply fail the test.

Comment: is there any way in the lib that I created to call a robot framework keyword? for example, in my switch statement (in the library) I would like to call my_keyword_1 (which is implemented in test.robot) ?

Comment: @LouGyde Yes there is a way, you can check it already in my answer.

`BuiltIn().run_keyword('Log Many', 'arg1 - case1', 'arg2 - case1')`

You can pass your keyword's name as string along with any of its args and run it with the `BuiltIn().run_keyword()` keyword, just as I did with `Log Many`, `Log`, `No Operation` and `Log To Console`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for  `--removekeywords` and `--flattenkeywords` command line options
For more details have a look at [Removing and flattening keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.9.2/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#removing-and-flattening-keywords)

your code suggests that all this conditions are looping under for loop from `\` an older syntax of `FOR` loop. So by using

`robot --removekeywords FOR testuitefilename.robot` will produce output something like in the below screenshot. In most of the cases passed steps does not required and I think this suffice to serve your requirement.

`FOR` - This mode remove all passed iterations from for loops except the last one.

[image]

Other possibility is approaching to this problem in other way instead of looking for the option to not to log the false condition keywords in the logs. for example -

- From the code I could see `'${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'` this condition is common. So instead of checking it all over check it once.
- Instead of looping all over use the `IN` & `List` or `Dictionary` to check the `${type}` variable value exist in the one of collection. And get that value using keywords.
- Check this condition before hand `'${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' != 'None'` and then use variable as part of keyword syntax to call the specific keyword

This I could reduce to  -

```
*Test cases
Run Keyword If  '${DealId}' != 'None' and '${ScenarioId}' !='None'    Execute the type of Keyword   SiteSelection

*Keywords
Execute the type of Keyword      
    [Arguments]       ${type}

    ${Type_list}=   Create List     ImportExportParams  BulkApplyCheapest   SiteSelection   SiteSelectionFile   
        ...         SiteSelectionFile2  SiteSelectionMultiple

    ${Status}  ${index}  Run Keyword And Ignore Error      Get Index From List     ${Type_list}        ${type}
    ${Keyword_type}       Get From List       ${Type_list}    ${index}
    log     ${Status} ${index}
    Run Keyword     Call_API_${Keyword_type}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I think these will not remove `Run Keyword If` entries only what is inside them. Also these will remove every `Run Keyword If` logs not just the ones where the condition was evaluated to `False`. Although I could be wrong, can you provide an example in which `--removekeywords` or `--flattenkeywords` are parametrized? :)

Comment: @BenceKaulics Haven't tried this. Would try and see if I could get close to it. But this could turn into workaround so I shared.

Comment: Well, even with `--removekeywords all` I could see all `Run Keyword If` and its args in the logs, only everything below them was removed and `Keyword data removed using --RemoveKeywords option.` was visible. So it was the same as in the OP's image.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Have updated the answer with my findings. Almost removed `If` and `FOR`

Comment: Nice catch with the `FOR` loop and the refactor.